# How to get posterior number of trials using Beta-Binomial model?

Tags: r, bayesian, beta-binomial-distribution

Let's say $y$ is known, is there any way to compute the number of trials N such that $P(\theta_N<\theta_0|y)=0.95$ ?

For the sake of the example, let's say #successes $y=0$ and prior probability $\theta_0=0.001$ with prior $Beta(1,500)$. One solution is to test all value of n until `pbeta(0.001,1,500+n)` $\geq0.95$. After testing from n=1...N, I can get N=2495. But, is there any way to calculate N directly--instead of testing all values of N?

Comment: I'm a little bit confused, which is your likelihood function and which is your prior, and what is the $\theta_{N}$?

Comment: @Fiodor1234 I am guessing that the likelihood function is binomial with parameters $N$ and $\theta$ and since "#successes $y=0$" is $(1-\theta)^N$, while the prior is $\text{Beta}(1,500)$ so the posterior is $\text{Beta}(1,500+N)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could give more details the question.  I think you are pointing to `pbeta(0.001,1,500+2495)` being `0.95004`

Let's try to deal will this more generally with a significance level $\alpha$, a prior $\text{Beta}(1,\beta_0)$, a binomial observation of $y=0$ and an assumed higher limit $\theta_0$ for the interval of integration.

Then you want $$\int_0^{\theta_0} (\beta_0+N)(1-\theta)^{\beta_0+N-1}\ge 1-\alpha$$
and the integration gives $1-(1-\theta_0)^{\beta_0+N} \ge 1-\alpha$ and so ${\beta_0+N} \ge \frac{\log\alpha }{\log(1-\theta_0)}$ - both logarithms are negative - and thus $$N \ge \frac{\log\alpha }{\log(1-\theta_0)} -\beta_0.$$

In your example $\beta_0=500, \alpha=0.05, \theta_0=0.001$ and you get $N\ge 2494.234$ as you found.

The integration is made easier by having $\alpha_0=1$ and $y=0$.

Comment: As an aside, it is not a coincidence that $\beta_0+N \approx 3000$, so about three times $\frac{1}{0.001}$.  This is close to the frequentist [rule of three](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_three_(statistics)) for when an event is not observed in a large sample

Comment: for the integration part, can you explain where does the $(\beta_0+N)$ come from? Shouldn't it be $(\beta_0+1)(1-\theta)^{\beta_0+N-1}$?

Comment: @Algorithman It is the multiplicative constant in the Beta density.  You need $\int_0^1 K(1-\theta)^{\beta_0+N-1}\, d\theta =1$ and find this requires $K=\beta_0+N$